# Magento 1.9 Multi Vendor Site will not save new product on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Fvo.png)I am running magento 1.9 and the apptha multi vendor marketplace and when you register as a customer and go through to add a new product it will not save the product and goes to a http 500 error. I have contacted my hosting provider and they are telling me it isn't anything on thier end, but that maybe there are settings that need to be specific for magento stores. Has anyone ever run into this problem or does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi there @Brenda , if it is HTTP Code - 500 , then it is a code of Internal Server Error , it is throwing from the server by PHP , for more confirmation please check the network tab of the browser dev tools and check the request in that and analyse more and if possible please provide screenshots of what response thrown in the network tab.
This was my best guess.Thanks

Comment: I added 2 images to my post that are the errors it is throwing. I have no idea what this even means or where to look to fix it.